# Slides em HTML5/CSS3 - Background não muda

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, animação

Galera preciso de ajuda com CSS3. Estou usando o keyframes/animation para alterar a imagem de várias classes article, no qual estou usando CSS para alterar o background nas seguintes porcentagens 0, 30, 35,65, 70, 100. O problema esta no fato de que a primeira classe chamada milha, esta mudando perfeitamente e eu apenas repliquei o código para as demais classes, a penúltima classe esta alterando porém apenas 2 imagens. Segue o código abaixo

HTML5

```html
            <div class="secao">
            <section>    
                <article class="milha"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge1">categoria 1</span></h3></article>
                <article class="farol"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge2">categoria 1</span></h3></article>
                <article class="roda"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge3">categoria 1</span></h3></article>
                <article class="capo"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge4">categoria 1</span></h3></article>
                <article class="retrovisor"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge5">categoria 1</span></h3></article>
                <article class="porta"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge6">categoria 1</span></h3></article>
            </section>
           </div>
```

Abaixo segue o CSS3 utilizado para alterar estas classes.

```css
.milha{
    background-image: url(b2.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-animation: slide 5s infinite;
    animation: slide 5s infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;   

}

.farol{
    background-image:url(e2.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-animation:farol 5s infinite;
    animation:farol 5s infinite;
}
.roda{
    background-image:url(e7.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-animation: slidesRoda 5s infinite;
    animation:roda 5s infinite;
}
.capo{
    background-image:url(e5.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-animation: capo 5s infinite;
    animation:capo 5s infinite;
}

.porta{
    background-image:url(d1.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-animation:porta 5s infinite;
    animation:porta 5s infinite;
}

.retrovisor{
    background-image:url(a1.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:12px;
    -webkit-animation:retrovisor 5s infinite;
    animation:retrovisor 5s infinite;
}


@keyframes farol{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(e2.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(e3.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(e4.jpg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes farol{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(e2.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(e3.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(e4.jpg);
    }
    
}


@keyframes roda{


    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(e7.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(e8.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(e9.jpg);
    }
    
}

@-webkit-keyframes roda{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(e7.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(e8.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(e9.jpg);
    }
}


@keyframes capo{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(e5.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(e6.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(e10.jpg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes capo{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(e5.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(e6.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(e10.jpg);
    }
}

@keyframes porta{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(d1.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(d2.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(d3.jpg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes porta{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(d1.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(d2.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(d3.jpg);
    }
    
}

@keyframes retrovisor{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(a1.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(a2.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(a3.jpg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes retrovisor{
     0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(a1.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(a2.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(a3.jpg);
    }
}


@keyframes slide{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(b1.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(b2.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(b3.jpg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(b1.jpg);
    }

    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(b2.jpg);
    }

    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(b3.jpg);
    }
}
```

Vale lembrar que todas as imagens que estão contidas nos códigos estão na mesma pasta.

Comment: Publio vc falou que todas as imagens estão na mesma pasta correto. *Então confere se todas estão com a extensão **.JPG** ou se tem alguma imagem **.GIF** ou **.PNG***. Eu testei aqui e funcionou normal com a minhas imagens se quiser eu posto meu código. OBS: a tag `<H3>` no html vc só fechou, mas não abriu...

Comment: realmente tinha uma ou outra imagem com formato errado, porém isso não mudou absolutamente nada no funcionamento dos slides, estranho...

Comment: Jovem publiquei uma resposta com o código funcionando, olha se está igual ao seu. Reparei que tem alguns nomes de classes que não estão no CSS que vc postou na pergunta `"badge badge-secondary"`, avalie isso. Mas veja abaixo o código funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publio estou colocando a resposta apenas para vc ver que está funcionando direitinho trocando 3 imagens por elemento. Só dei uma reduzida no CSS para facilitar a leitura.

*Olhe o código abaixo funcionando e compare com o seu*, se as pastas das imagens estão ok e vc já conferiu a extensão dos arquivos como eu sugeri no comentário as vezes esse código pode te ajudar.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
article {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
}

.milha,
.farol,
.roda,
.capo,
.porta,
.retrovisor {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius:12px;
}
.milha{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    -webkit-animation: slide 5s infinite;
    animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
.farol{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    -webkit-animation: farol 5s infinite;
    animation: slide 5s infinite;
}
.roda{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    -webkit-animation: roda 5s infinite;
    animation: roda 5s infinite;
}
.capo{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    -webkit-animation: capo 5s infinite;
    animation: capo 5s infinite;
}
.porta{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    -webkit-animation: porta 5s infinite;
    animation: porta 5s infinite;
}
.retrovisor{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    -webkit-animation: retrovisor 5s infinite;
    animation: retrovisor 5s infinite;
}


@keyframes farol{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes farol{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
}

@keyframes roda{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    
}

@-webkit-keyframes roda{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
}


@keyframes capo{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes capo{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
}

@keyframes porta{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes porta{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    
}

@keyframes retrovisor{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes retrovisor{

    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
}


@keyframes slide{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide{
    
    0%, 30%{
    background-image: url(http://placeskull.com/100/100);
    }
    35%, 65%{
    background-image: url(http://placecage.com/100/100);
    }
    70%, 100%{
    background-image: url(http://fillmurray.com/100/100);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="secao">
    <section>    
        <article class="milha"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge1"><h3>categoria 1</h3></span></article>
        <article class="farol"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge2"><h3>categoria 2</h3></span></article>
        <article class="roda"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge3"><h3>categoria 3</h3></span></article>
        <article class="capo"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge4"><h3>categoria 4</h3></span></article>
        <article class="retrovisor"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge5"><h3>categoria 5</h3></span></article>
        <article class="porta"><span class="badge badge-secondary" id="badge6"><h3>categoria 6</h3></span></article>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu! eu copiei e colei os links das imagens que vc utilizou para testar, vi que o código estava funcional, custou-me a acreditar porque eu verifiquei várias vezes as imagens e alterei os formatos, mas agora já sei como resolver, obrigado mesmo cara!

Comment: Quem bom que deu certo jovem! Boa sorte com o projeto, qq dúvida estamos aqui!